# nodejs/mongoose authentication issue on dotcloud

Tags: node.js, mongoose, dotcloud

I'm using node.js with mongoose which cannot connect to the DB failing with authentication issue.

Using the connection env variable uri:
:mongodb://root:*********@[appname]-[user]-db-0.azva.dotcloud.net:4518
And the result is:
{ [MongoError: auth fails] name: 'MongoError', errmsg: 'auth fails', ok: 0 }

Tried to build up own conn URI based on the environment variables like DOTCLOUD_DB_MONGODB_HOST etc, the URI is correct, passing to the env variable but the problem is still this based on the DB logs:
db.0     Sat Dec 29 00:31:08 [conn66] auth: couldn't find user root, admin.system.users

Could anyone help me how to resolve this missing user root?

Thank you in advance!!!

update: I logged in to mongodb console on the mongodb node via "use admin" and cannot authenticate with that username and password either. Nor create a new user and password. :(

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. 
The dotcloud system has provisioned the db instance badly somehow.
Creating a new app, everything is working fine.